# React prevent css animation restarting every state change

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations, react-functional-component

I have two child components, an image gallery and a hidden components which will display the clicked image of the gallery at full size.

```
    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedtIndex] = useState(0);
    const [galleryVisible, setGalleryVisible] = useState(false);

    const FirstComponent = () => {
        return (
           <div className={'gallery-container'}>
               <div class='img fade-1' onClick={() => handleClick(1)}>Image 1</div>
               <div class='img fade-2' onClick={() => handleClick(2)}>Image 2</div>
               <div class='img fade-3' onClick={() => handleClick(3)}>Image 3</div>
               [...]
           </div>
        )
    }

    const handleClick = (index) => {
        setSelectedtIndex(index)
        setGalleryVisible(true)
    }

    const SecondComponent = ({ index }) => {
        return (
            <div className={`selected-img`}>Selected : {index} (But the fading animation shouldn't restart è_é)</div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <>
            <FirstComponent/>
            {galleryVisible && 
                <SecondComponent index={selectedIndex} />
            }
        </>
    )
```

The issue is that I also have a fade-in animation on the first component, and every time I click on an image to display the second component, that animation resets due to the rerender of react on state change.

```
    &.fade-1 {
      animation-delay: 0s
    }
    &.fade-2 {
      animation-delay: 0.5s
    }
     &.fade-3 {
      animation-delay: 1s
    }
```

I don't know how can I only change the second component when the state is changed from a click on the first one... I tried to play with useMemo but couldn't get it to work.

Here is a codepen reproducing the issue : https://codepen.io/disgallion/pen/zYjqPBE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the first component outside of `App` and pass `handleClick` to its props:

```
  const FirstComponent = ({handleClick}) => {
    return (
      <div className={'gallery-container'}>
        <div class='img fade-1' onClick={() => handleClick(1)}>1</div>
        <div class='img fade-2' onClick={() => handleClick(2)}>2</div>
        <div class='img fade-3' onClick={() => handleClick(3)}>3</div>
      </div>
    )
  }

const App = () => {
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedtIndex] = useState(0);
  const [galleryVisible, setGalleryVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = (index) => {
    console.log('click')
    setSelectedtIndex(index)
    setGalleryVisible(true)
  }


  
  const SecondComponent = ({ index }) => {
    return (
      <div className={`selected-img`}>Selected : {index} (But the fading animation shouldn't restart è_é)</div>
    )
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      Click on an image to open the fullsize gallery:
      <FirstComponent handleClick={handleClick} />
      {galleryVisible && 
        <SecondComponent index={selectedIndex} />
      }
    </>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,
document.getElementById("root"))
```

Now the state change of `App` will not trigger a re-render in `FirstComponent`

Comment: It works on the codepen, but somehow not in my project... Maybe because I'm in a component that I export to App.js? That's the only difference...

Comment: Just separate the components into there own files and export them to App.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, that will works but would means that handleClick and the states would be defined at App level right? If so, isn't this bad react design?

Comment: Passing props from parent to child is very common in React.